# Can I launch a FullTrust Win32 app from within a UWP app's out-of-process background task?

Tags: c#, uwp, background-task, full-trust

I needed to read the registry every system login in order to determine whether to launch a notification or not. So I had to create an out-of-process background task with `SystemTriggerType.SessionConnected` to do this. The background task implementation would look something like this:

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    
    Task launchFullTrust = LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync(); //Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher as an async task
    launchFullTrust.Wait();

    BackgroundTaskDeferral appServiceDeferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    AppServiceTriggerDetails details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as AppServiceTriggerDetails;
    Connection = details.AppServiceConnection; // AppServiceConnection object
    ...
    // perform data acquisition
}
```

But because this background process is triggered by the session connectivity, it is guaranteed that `taskInstance` will not contain `AppServiceTriggerDetails`, or anything related to the `AppServiceTrigger` at all. Considering this, is there a way to receive a handle to the `AppServiceConnection` connection from the background task, and not from the UWP app itself?

Comment: Could you please tell me if the main program(your UWP app) is running when the background task is triggered?

Comment: Hi there, no the app is not running. This is also the case for my intentions with the background task.

Comment: Just an update, to answer the main question if it is possible to launch a FullTrust Win32 app from an out-of-process background task: Yes, but the Win32 app will trigger the `OnBackgroundTaskActivated` function of the Main UWP application. This means it would be better to continue from said function and obtain a handle to the `AppServiceConnection` from there. This situation seems workable for me, I guess I can continue with this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the main question if it is possible to launch a FullTrust Win32 app from an out-of-process background task: **Yes**

But the Win32 app will trigger the `OnBackgroundTaskActivated` function of the Main UWP application. This means it would be better to continue from said function and obtain a handle to the `AppServiceConnection` from there. I was hoping to have a way to receive the connection on the background-task itself, but this situation seems workable for me. I am able to continue with this approach.